# Is this the correct way to use EXISTS?

Tags: sql, exists, min

I've been doing some SQL for an exam I have on thursday and I have doubts if I'm using the EXISTS statement correctly.

So, here I have a DB with 2 tables

```
    Machines                Maintenance
    ============            ==============
PK  ID_Machine          PK  ID_Machine  FK
    Name                PK  ID_Task     FK
    Date_bought             Date
```

So, the query they want me to write says *"Show all data from the oldest machine that has not received any  maintenance in 2011"*

The way I did it is the following:

```
SELECT M.ID_MACHINE, M.NAME, M.DATE_BOUGHT
FROM MACHINES M
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT MA.*
                  FROM MAINTENANCE MA
                  WHERE MA.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE
                  AND YEAR(MA.DATE) = 2011)                  
AND EXISTS (SELECT MIN(M2.DATE_BOUGHT)
              FROM MACHINE M2
              WHERE M2.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE)
```

Is this a correct way to do this query? does it makes sense that I use SELECT MIN() inside a EXISTS statement?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Well....what happens when you try to run the query?

Comment: Well, the thing is that I actually don't have this DB created in any DBMS. It's just an exercise in the textbook and I'm solving it in a piece of paper. Unfortunatelly, the textbook doesn't have the answers, so that's why I was asking :)

Comment: well for a start, you need an `AND` *instead of* the second `WHERE`. Also, never use `SELECT MIN()` inside an `EXISTS` - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, you're absolutely right, I missed the AND there.
Also, that was basically my doubt. I thought that by putting "SELECT MIN()" inside the EXISTS statement, it would erease all the other rows but the one with the MIN(Date_Bought). I guess I was wrong then!

Comment: What is the third table `machine m2` you use in `exists`?

Comment: @a1ex07 it's just an aux copy of the machine table that I use for the subquery

Comment: @nachoargentina: If it's the same table (`machines`) , `exists` always returns true because there is always exactly 1 record that matches the criterion `M2.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE`. (`ID_MACHINE` is primary key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use exists, it only validates that a piece of data is returned for the filters (joins and where). Often, you will see exists queries with select 1 from.... This is because the actual return values are not used.

This was a novel idea, and one I had to test out personally. However, as I stated above, the return data is ignored for the most part. It only cares that the join and where filters match and does not care about the MIN, even though it does seem to be a filter in itself. It is more of an aggregation, so the underlying data remains, it seems. The first exists is valid, but the next part does need work. I have updated it below for what I would do.

```
SELECT M.ID_MACHINE, M.NAME, M.DATE_BOUGHT
FROM MACHINES M
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MAINTENANCE MA
              WHERE MA.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE
              AND YEAR(MA.DATE) = 2011)                  
    AND M.ID_MACHINE = (SELECT TOP 1 M2.ID_MACHINE
          FROM MACHINE M2
          WHERE M2.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE
          ORDER BY M2.DATE_BOUGHT)
```

Comment: Right, so then in my case, with the EXISTS condition I'm trying to select the oldest machine...that's why I included a MIN() in the select statement of the SubQuery. I thought that by doing that, the EXISTS statement would eliminate all other machines BUT the one that has the MIN(Date_bought) in it. Is this the case? or am I tackling this the wrong way?

Comment: Updating my response, but the short answer is that you are indeed tackling this the wrong way. It was a novel idea though :)

Comment: Sorry, disregard my last comment, I didn't read all your comment thru to the end, just the first paragraph. So, you think it might work this way? I thought so, since as you said, the MIN() would in theory act as a filter. I would try to test this in an actual database as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: My response has been updated to explain why the MIN does not actually work after testing it out and really thinking it through. As to the exists, I would keep to the convention of SELECT 1 so that you always remember that the actual data returned does not matter as much as the fact that it returns at all (ie. that the return data exists). It was mainly the aggregation effect that messed you (and myself) up. If you like the response, dont forget to upvote and choose a response that most accurately answers your question with an acceptance check :)

Comment: Note that `SELECT TOP 1` is TSQL and not standard. `FETCH FIRST` is the standard... But is not required to answer the question.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks Yuval. I am much more versed on MSSQL, and appreciate the catch

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> 8.8
>
> ```
>      Function
>
>      Specify a test for a non-empty set.
>
>      Format
>
>      <exists predicate> ::= EXISTS <table subquery>
>
>
>      Syntax Rules
>
>         None.
>
>      Access Rules
>
>
>         None.
>
>      General Rules
>
>      1) Let T be the result of the <table subquery>.
>
>      2) If the cardinality of T is greater than 0, then the result of
>         the <exists predicate> is true; otherwise, the result of the
>         <exists predicate> is false.
>
>      Leveling Rules
>
>      1) The following restrictions apply for Intermediate SQL:
>
>           None.
>
>      2) The following restrictions apply for Entry SQL in addition to
>         any Intermediate SQL restrictions:
>
>           None.
> ```

So, no, there are no special rules on the syntax of the subquery (only that it's valid).  The `exists` statement merely cares about whether or not it returns any rows.

Comment: Ok, so in this case, the EXISTS statement will return true for one specific row in the M2 table. Since that table has an external reference to the main table in my query, does that mean that by doing that, it will rule out all of the rows in my main table except for the one that has the MIN(Date_bought) value? Because that's basically what I'm aiming for

Comment: No, it won't remove any rows from any table.  It is neither a `delete` nor a `truncate` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` as boolean conditions you can tack onto your queries where clause. They're used to check if other data conditions are true or false in relation to the data you're looking at.

```
SELECT M.ID_MACHINE, M.NAME, M.DATE_BOUGHT
FROM MACHINES M

-- DO NOT want a machine with a maintenance year of 2011
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MAINTENANCE MA
                  WHERE MA.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE
                  AND YEAR(MA.DATE) = 2011)      

-- DO want there to be a matching ID in the Machine table            
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MACHINE M2
              WHERE M2.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE)
```

As Justin mentioned, the return values of the subqueries aren't used, so `SELECT 1` is the convention for `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: But, as I just edited my post, MIN kind of acts like a filter in itself...so I do wonder if having MIN would work or not....I have never tried it, and in theory it could work. I updated my response to question this. I may load some dummy data to see :)

Comment: Tested it and it fails. I am re-updating my answer :)

Comment: @JustinPihony Ok, tx for testing that for me! good to know that it was not right then. I appretiate it man.

Comment: @pat tx for pointing that out also. From now on, I will think of EXISTS as boolean condition

Answer (score 1):

Your first use of `EXISTS` seems correct, but the second seems to be off. You want to check whether the machine is oldest, but you're checking whether a machine exists with the same `MACHINE_ID` (the use of `MIN` there has no affect on the result of the `EXISTS` function).

I'm not a DB admin, but take into account sub-queries may be costly in some implementations, and on others they may be optimized when placed in an `EXISTS` function. So stringpoet's code should be considered when you actually need the code to run... though as I commented you'll need to `GROUP BY` all other fields.

Also note that you shouldn't use the keyword `WHERE` twice, but join your conditions with `AND` / `OR`.

Here's my correction to yours and stringpoet's code:

```
SELECT M.ID_MACHINE, M.NAME, MIN(M.DATE_BOUGHT)
FROM MACHINES M
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT MA.*
                  FROM MAINTENANCE MA
                  WHERE MA.ID_MACHINE = M.ID_MACHINE
                  AND YEAR(MA.DATE) = 2011)                  
GROUP BY M.ID_MACHINE, M.NAME
```

Comment: Ok, great, that made things much clearer! tx Yuval, I will use your code instead the ones with the EXIST for my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a better way to go about it.

```
SELECT TOP 1 MIN(A.Date_bought), A.ID_Machine, A.Name
FROM Machines A
JOIN Maintenance B on A.ID_Machine = B.ID_Machine
WHERE DATEPART(year, B.Date) != '2011'
GROUP BY A.Date_bought, A.ID_Machine, A.Name
```

Comment: -1: The OP was asking whether or not his/her query was valid, not to have it rewritten.

Comment: I think that would fail since `MIN` is aggregate and you have no `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thank you, missed the GROUP BY :)  Also, to Jack, he also asked if it's the right way to do it, which I don't think it is, so I offered another solution. No need to down vote it when I only have 8 rep here. Jeez. lol

Comment: Hey! that's a much easier way to do it. Thanks for that, it's really helpful.
But yes, I would also like to know if they way I did it would work as well, mostly to find out if the EXISTS condition is supposed to work as I think is work. 
Anyway, tx again

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that would work, as EXISTS is a conditional statement that returns a boolean. Your EXISTS statements could make your query actually look for "WHERE TRUE" or "WHERE FALSE", which wouldn't produce good results. You generally only use EXISTS in an IF statement to see if something exists before you decide what to do with it.